# Error while Calling R method from python

Tags: python, r

I am trying to call Random forest predict method coded in R from python. Using rpy2 to achieve the same.

My requirement is to call the predict method in real time for each line(representing a session) and get the prediction output in python for tagging that session.

I have already got the trained model and loaded in the R. Created a dataframe and calling the predict method.

Getting one error.

Here is the snippet from python code.

```
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
import rpy2.robjects as ro

pandas2ri.activate()

ro.r('require(xlsx)')
ro.r('require(caret)')
ro.r('require(rpart)')
ro.r('require(e1071)')
ro.r('library(randomForest)')
ro.r('library(stringr)')
ro.r('library(plyr)')
ro.r('library(sqldf)')
ro.r('library(splitstackshape)')
ro.r('library(cluster)')
ro.r('library(fpc)')
ro.r('fit <-readRDS("RFmodel.rds")')


dataRec = ro.DataFrame({ "protocoldesc":protocoldesc ,"serverflag":serverflag ,....})

#Assign it to name test in R
ro.globalenv['test'] = dataRec;

ro.r('predboom<-predict(fit, test, type="response")')

##creating a column for the pred
ro.r('test$pred <- predboom')
ro.r('content_type <-as.char(test$pred)')
print(ro.r('content_type'))
```

Getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestAnalytics.py", line 717, in <module>
    ro.r('predboom<-predict(fit, test, type="response")')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py", line 359, in __call__
    res = self.eval(p)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 178, in __call__
    return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 106, in __call__
    res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'skew1' not found
```

Don't know what this skew1 object is and how to fix it.

Comment: Is this all the code? What is *protocoldesc* and *serverflag* as no assignment is shown? Also, why not have Python simply run the R script from command line? Right now, you do not really use the Python environment and are just binding R commands and [rpy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-dev/html/introduction.html) allows more integration of Python's data structures instead of repeat `ro.r()` calls.

Comment: No it is not all the code. It is just part of the code. I pasted only relevant things. I am receiving real time streams and doing many different aggregations in the python code and storing them in mongo and sending that to dashboard for realtime view. I need to get the prediction value to tag the data and send to dashboard too. 

BTW I got the issue which is the RDS file I loaded. It was having some more variables which I was not knowing(Was having old code). 

Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: I don't know if there is any other way to do realtime request response to get prediction value.

Most of my code is in Python and some is in spark. I am planning to use SparkR in near future, to use R model for the analytics. 

Please suggest if there are any alternatives.

Comment: Thanks @Parfait, I missed the rpy2 part from your comment. Later I did try that by combining the calls in a r function and calling that through rpy2 but didn't got the performance required as I am need it in real time. 

For my realtime need, I moved to python completely. I am training the model and then serialising that using [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html). Then loading the trained model using pickle then performing rest of the functionality.